# How to create a Bash listener to receive PHP requests?

Tags: bash

I'm currently using an Apache server with PHP to listen for requests from another server. The server either loads a page with arguments (GET) or posts values to a page (POST) to trigger an event.

I'm wondering if I could make a Bash listener to listen for requests instead of having a whole Apache server to listen.

If this is possible, how would I do so? It would have to be able to execute other Bash scripts. My current method uses PHP's exec function, which I don't think is speed optimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 'man bash`:

> /dev/tcp/host/port
>                        If host is a valid hostname or Internet address, and port
>                        is  an integer port number or service name, bash attempts
>                        to open a TCP connection to the corresponding socket.

[Here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-23/bash/examples/scripts/websrv.sh) is a web server that is distributed with Bash.

On my system, its `/usr/share/doc/bash/examples/scripts/websrv.sh`